# Iterate over excel worksheet using interop C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, interop

I have a `DataTable` used to create a Worksheet with `Interop`. Once I have the Worksheet I want to iterate over this Worksheet to get some cells that meets a condition and input there a new value.

For example, the next table is my Worksheet, once it is created I want to iterate over the worksheet and try to **get only the values that are in red cells**... So the cells have to meet a condition.

[image]

How could I get these values, using `SQL` or `Interop` have some method to do this?

Comment: I would suggest you use open XML sdk to read excel. Interop is decade old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the values that are in red cells.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pathToExcelFile = @"D:\test.xlsx";

            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(pathToExcelFile, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

            Excel._Worksheet sheet = (Excel._Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range ran = sheet.UsedRange;
            for (int x = 1; x <= ran.Rows.Count; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 1; y <= ran.Columns.Count; y++)
                {
                    var CellColor = sheet.UsedRange.Cells[x, y].Interior.Color; 
                    if(CellColor==GetCustomColor(Color.Red))
                    {
                        string value = sheet.Cells[x, y].value.ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine(value);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        private static  Double GetCustomColor(Color color)
        {
            int nColor = color.ToArgb();
            int blue = nColor & 255;
            int green = nColor >> 8 & 255;
            int red = nColor >> 16 & 255;
            return Convert.ToDouble(blue << 16 | green << 8 | red);
        }
```

Excel file:

[image]

Result:

[image]